# Movement towards object in pygame

Tags: pygame

I have this pygame where I want my bus to move towards passengers and collect them...Now i can't get bus to move itself in a right way, but it moves 45deg right down. Plese help me to clean the code and settle this as it should be

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
from pygame.math import Vector2
from pygame.locals import *

class Bus:
    def __init__(self):
        self.body = [Vector2(5,10), Vector2(6,10), Vector2(7,10)]
        self.bus = pygame.image.load("bus.png").convert()
        self.bus.set_colorkey((255, 242, 0))  # Set color as transparent
        self.bus_rect = self.bus.get_rect(center=(143, 150))
        
    def draw_bus(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.bus, self.bus_rect.topleft)

    def move_towards_passenger(self, passenger_pos):
        if self.bus_rect.center != passenger_pos:  # Check if the bus is not at the passenger's position
            direction = Vector2(self.bus_rect.center) - Vector2(passenger_pos)
            if direction.length() > 0:  # Check if direction vector has non-zero length
                direction.normalize_ip()
                speed = 5  # Adjust the speed as needed
                movement = direction * speed
                # Calculate the new position for the bus
                new_center = self.bus_rect.center + movement
                # Update the bus's position
                self.bus_rect.center = new_center
    


class Passenger:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.pos = Vector2(x, y)
        self.passenger = pygame.image.load("passenger.png").convert()
        self.passenger.set_colorkey((255, 242, 0))  # Set color as transparent

    def draw_passenger(self, surface):
        passenger_rect = pygame.Rect(self.pos.x * cell_size, self.pos.y * cell_size, cell_size, cell_size)
        surface.blit(self.passenger, passenger_rect.topleft)

pygame.init()

# defining cells
cell_size = 40
cell_number = 20

# the display surface
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((cell_number * cell_size, 562))
pygame.display.set_caption("GroupT1 9waysGame Task4")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # influencing time and speed of the game

# Load music file
pygame.mixer.music.load('lobby_time.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)  # -1 means play the music in an infinite loop

# Start the music 1 second earlier
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, start=1)

# Set volume
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.3)

# Check the music
music_playing = True

# the Surface objects
map_image = pygame.image.load("map.jpg").convert()

bus = Bus()
passenger = Passenger(random.randint(0, cell_number - 1), random.randint(0, cell_number - 1))  # Initialize Passenger with random coordinates

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # event quit by pressing esc
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

    # Call move_towards_passenger method to move the bus towards the passenger
    bus.move_towards_passenger(passenger.pos)

 

    screen.blit(map_image, (0, 0))  # blit the map image
    passenger.draw_passenger(screen)  # draw the passenger on the screen
    bus.draw_bus(screen)  # draw the bus on the screen

    pygame.display.update()  # all elements drawn here
    clock.tick(60)
```

I tried to change direction ( direction = Vector2(self.bus_rect.center) - Vector2(passenger_pos) ) ... to direction =Vector2(passenger_pos) - Vector2(self.bus_rect.center) ... then it just moves 45deg left up...